# Erlang: How do you return an element of a list?

Tags: erlang

For example: `[{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}]`. I want to pick on the list with an argument (being `c`) and it will return `d`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use few approaches or use Erlang functions from the standard library(like [lists](https://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) etc.) or you can create your own, eg:

[List Comprehensions](https://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html)

```erlang
1> List = [{a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}].
2> Being = e.
3> [Result] = [Y || {X, Y} <- List, Being =:= X].
4> Result.
f
```

[Functions](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html)

```erlang
1> GetVal = fun GetVal (_, [])                -> not_found;
                GetVal (X, [{X, Result} | _]) -> Result; 
                GetVal (X, [_ | T])           -> GetVal(X, T)
            end.
2> List = [{a,b}, {c,d}, {e,f}].
3> Being = e.
4> GetVal(Being, List).
f
```

The simple way to use [Pattern Matching](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/patterns.html) and [List Handling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a program that prints each tuple in the list.
2. Write a program that prints just the second element of each tuple in the list.
3. Write a program that takes an argument `Target` along with a `List`.  When you find the tuple `{Target, Right}`, print our `Right`.

Comment: yea thank you, i figured it out on how to do that. i got it working thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using functions from the standard library, you can use [lists:keyfind/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) or [proplists:get_value/2,3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_value-2).